# Nikon NX Studio works!.. but crop window is offset to upper left. How to get crop window directly over image?

Tags: 22.04, wine, editor, photo

Nikon NX Studio works!.. but crop window is offset to upper left.  How to get crop window directly over image? [image of nikon nx studio with crop window offset to the upper left. I needs to be over the image itself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIIMl.jpg)